# solr 503 error when going througn php application

Tags: php, apache, solr, jetty

My php application is setup to call `localhost:8983` to talk to jetty/solr and return search results.

From a browser, I can get to `solr:8983` without any issue and see that jetty/solr is running.

the php application is running on apache.

The solr `schema.xml` is setup correctly, a direct copy. I've checked permissions, everything that I can think of. I don't see anything in the solr logs or the apache logs.

From what I can find, most `503` errors are issues where `localhost:8983`isn't running, but that is fine for me.

Any ideas? Why doesn't my php application talking to jetty solr over localhost?

Comment: Any error log on either jetty or apache?

Comment: plz show the URI you try to reach from php?

Comment: There is nothing the the jetty or apache error logs that indicate any issues. I notice that when I clear out the /data/ directory form my collection and restart solr, it creates 3 files (segment_1, segment.gen, and write.lock) but when doing this on my development machine, there are a lot more files created.

the URI is 'localhost:8983/search?q=[search term]

Comment: The URI I am trying to reach from php is 'localhost:8983/solr/'

Answer (score 0):

A configuration change to the php.ini, changing allow_url_fopen to On resolved this.